# Semi-supervised training in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I wonder whether the following model is possible in Keras, or whether one needs to drop down to tensorflow.

Imagine a large dataset of unlabeled data, and a (possibly much) smaller one of labeled data.

The intuition is to train simultaneously for two objectives: accuracy of classification for the labeled data, and confidence of classification for the unlabeled data.

The idea would be to run all the data (labeled and unlabeled) forward through to the final softmax layer, as usual.

Then, the batch is split into two sets: the labeled exemplars and the unlabeled ones.

For the labeled data, the error/loss is computed as usual, say cross-entropy.
For the unlabeled data, we pick some function of the dispersion of the categorical distributions.  A very basic one would be (the mean of) 1 minus the max(prob) for the exemplar.

Now the two "errors" -- the entropy and the dispersion -- are summed (subject to a weighting hyperparameter), and this value is the value to be minimized in the gradient descent.

In other words, the dispersion factor works as a sort of regularizer for the fit procedure.

I'm guessing that implementing this Keras would involve a custom loss function, but I'm not sure about splitting the batch, matching a subset up with the targets etc.  Any ideas very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find an example of a semi supervised model in keras : http://bjlkeng.github.io/posts/semi-supervised-learning-with-variational-autoencoders/

What he does is creating two models which share layers. One model has the labeled data as input and the other the unlabeled data.

The training is done using train on batch and alternating the labeled data and the unlabeled data.